# Persist a variable value in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package that contains a script task. I extent it by editing the script. 
The package runs periodically and I need to persist a date value in a variable. The value is the last time the package was run. The package is run from the SQL server agent. I have put the variable in the configuration xml for the package. I want to update the value in the xml once my package is run from the script task.

I have written the code like this

```
Dts.Variables["lastRunDate"].Properties["Value"].SetValue(Dts.Variables["lastRunDate"], DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The program runs, I am just not sure, what is the correct value for SetValue function's first parameter. the documentation is not much of a help. The script runs but the xml configuration file is not updated with the new value.

Update : I could save the value to the registry. I am not sure of the best practice here !!! It has security issues with the way packages are deployed and run under SQL server. :(

Can anyone please help with this ?

Comment: Why not store that value in "history" table?

Comment: Is that best practice ? to do that way ? I just don't want to put an extra table in the database for the package to run correctly. It is just an other dependency on the package.

Comment: Well it is always good practice to create history table to keep track of every time your package runs and its results. Extra table with few columns should not be a problem. I'm still a little unclear about your requirements for this date value.

Comment: @SaUce I have a http site where I get some csv files which are zipped (name + "<date when they put it>" + .zip). They put that every week. I need to pull in and process the csv files. I just need to save the last checked date somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running the package through the agent, couldn't you pull the last run date through some combination of the msdb.dbo.sysjob% tables?

**msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity**

```
SELECT  TOP 1 sja.start_execution_date
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sja
    ON  sj.job_id = sja.job_id
WHERE   sj.name = '<Agent Job Name>'
ORDER BY sja.start_execution_date DESC;
```

**msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory**

```
SELECT  TOP 1 run_date, run_time
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs
    ON  sj.job_id = sjs.job_id
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjh
    ON  sjs.job_id = sjh.job_id
    AND sjs.step_id = sjh.step_id
WHERE   sj.name = '<Agent Job Name>'
    AND sjs.step_name = '<Job Step Name>'
ORDER BY sjh.run_date DESC, sjh.run_time DESC;
```

Comment: That will help. Thanks. I hope, some one will post an easy way to persist variable values between runs.

Comment: SSIS benefits greatly from being able to take advantage of table-driven approaches.  Not wanting to add a table may be a valid concern, but I can not express with enough zeal how incredibly useful creating a small schema to keep track of my ETL processes has been.  With such a structure, you can record times, parameters, results and anything else you can figure out how to extract from the SSIS run, then quickly troubleshoot and automate monitoring which would be otherwise overly cumbersome.  Remember that SSIS is a database tool and should be used _with_ the database for maximum effect!

Comment: @Avarkx except when you actually integrate between some webservices and not necessarily SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a script task to directly manipulate the xml config file. I'm no guru on xml, so there may be a better way, but I can tell you how to append text to a file, so lacking a better solution, you could do this with Visual Basic.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Sub Main()

dim fileName as string
fileName = "C:\some\file\path\and\name.dtsconfig"
File.Delete(fileName)
File.AppendAllText(fileName, "<?xml version=" & chr(34) & "1.0" & chr(34) & "?>"
File.AppendAllText(fileName, "<DTSConfiguration><DTSConfigurationHeading></DTSConfigurationHeading>")
File.AppendAllText(fileName, "<Configuration ConfiguredType=" & chr(34) & "Property" & chr(34) & " Path = " & chr(34) & "\Package.Variables[User::lastRunDate].Properties[Value]" & chr(34) & "ValueType=" & chr(34) & "String" & chr(34) & ">")
File.AppendAllText(fileName, "<ConfiguredValue>" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "</ConfiguredValue></Configuration></DTSConfiguration>

End Sub
```

Comment: @CodeWeed Could you help me understand why this is horrible? Would it not address your situation (assuming you're using XML config)?

Comment: I never said it wasn't a dirty hack. It does address the situation, does it not?

Comment: @billinkc: The problem is the configuration files are loosely coupled with the packages and I have no other way read config file path. The DBA admin or the IT admins can put the config file anywhere in sql machine. I dont have a good way of knowing where the xml config from the extended script task. Moreover the package can be used later with other packages and they can override the configuration entries (with /Config or /SET). It would re-write the configuration file and I will end up loosing what I wrote to configuration file from the script task. I don't want that scenario to happen later.

Comment: That's lots of information we were not privy to and would thus be unable to formulate an answer to address those unstated concerns.

Comment: @billinkc : The way SSIS packages are developed, I thought it is obvious.

Comment: @billinkc: I could write the xml configuration with XML or XML to Linq in a type safe way. That is why I said earlier that it was horrible way just to persist a variable.

Comment: Ahhhh. Yeah. That is a lot of information that we didn't have. Looks like you found a much better answer though. You shouldn't ever assume that the way SSIS is developed where you work is how they are developed everywhere.

Comment: @ckuhn203 It is better, I just need to add an other task before the script task. Still I think there should be a straight forward way to persist values.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is add a cmd file to your job to set the variable at runtime, but you'd still have to write a file similar to my solution. I've been looking into this a good bit, and it seems that most people have a "configuration database" for this purpose.