# Persist Data in SSIS for Next Execution

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have data to load where I only need to pull records since the last time I pulled this data. There are no date fields to save this information in my destination table so I have to keep track of the maximum date that I last pulled. The problem is I can't see how to save this value in SSIS for the next time the project runs.

I saw this:
[Persist a variable value in SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143049/persist-a-variable-value-in-ssis-package)

but it doesn't work for me because there is another process that purges and reloads the data separate from my process. This means that I have to do more than just know the last time my process ran.

The only solution I can think of is to create a table but it seems a bit much to create a table to hold one field.

Comment: If you're not storing it in a database and the linked 'use a file' (XML or otherwise) strategy isn't palatable, your choices for persisting something between runs are pretty limited.  I suppose you could get crazy and rewrite your package source to set an internal variable.  A table in a database that can't easily be damaged seems to be a decent if not good choice for use with SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common thing to do.  You create an execution table that stores the package name, the start time, the end time, and whether or not the package failed/succeeded.  You are then able to pull the max start time of the last successfully ran execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't persist anything in a package between executions.

What you're talking about is a form of differential replication and this has been done many many times.

For differential replication it is normal to store some kind of state in the subscriber (the system reading the data) or the publisher (the system providing the data) that remembers what state you're up to.

So I suggest you:

1. Read up on differential replication design patterns
2. Absolutely put your mind at rest about writing data to a table

If you end up having more than one source system or more than one source table your storage table is not going to have just one record. Have a think about that. I answered a question like this the other day - you'll find over time that you're going to add handy things like the last time the replication ran, how long it took, how many records were transferred etc.

[Is it viable to have a SQL table with only one row and one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494630/is-it-viable-to-have-a-sql-table-with-only-one-row-and-one-column/30495123#30495123)

Answer (score 0):

TTeeple and Nick.McDermaid are absolutely correct, and you should follow their advice if humanly possible.

But if for some reason you don't have access to write to an execution table, you can always use a script task to read/write the last loaded date to a text file on on whatever local file-system you're running SSIS on.